# How to prevent selecting text on double click?

Tags: html, css, text, double-click

```
#btnLeft{
    width:40px;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
    background-color: #20a0a0;
    border: thin solid #099;
    border-radius:7px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Futura Md BT";
    font-size:large;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

This is a css button.
When user accidentally makes double click instead of single one, text inside the button becomes selected, i.e. - changes its background color.
How to prevent this selecting on double click ?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: @Michelle, what is the accepted solution on your link ? Also, i don't want to prevent selecting text in body part of page, just on buttons.

Comment: The "accepted" solution on @Michelle's link, is the solution with more votes. Why would that CSS code prevent the user from selecting text from other parts of the page? You put it on your #btnLeft{} and it does not interfere with the rest of your document.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

try little jquery

```
 $(element).mousedown(function(){ return false; })
```

with css try

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

Comment: NullPointer, Thanks a lot. Solved

Answer (score 7):

If you use a `<button>` or `<a>` tag and include an `href` attribute then the behaviour should be mitigated. And its more semantic :)

Comment: In certain situations, this isn't possible like when using checkbox inside a label :)